# Como enviar emails utilizando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, envio-de-email

Como todo bom *Content Management System* (CMS), é trivial uma página de contato. No meu não é diferente. Porém, queria fazê-lo sem ter que usar alguma outra linguagem e/ou tecnologia, exceto *JavaScript*. Meu objetivo é enviar *e-mails* para uma determinada *Inbox* (Ex.: contato@empresaxxx.com.br) com o requisito dito anteriormente. Segue abaixo um *Mockup* do `form` responsável pelo conteúdo a ser enviado:

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a [API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/) do [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com) para isso. É grátis para os doze mil primeiros envios mensais.

Você faria as chamadas à API com requisições HTTP simples. A forma mais fácil seria usando jQuery e a função `$.ajax` para `POST` (todas as chamadas à API são em `POST`).