# Formulário de Contato 2017

Tags: javascript, php, formulário

Minha dúvida é **simples e direta**: Atualmente, em 2017, com o avanço do Javascript... Existe alguma forma de eu fazer um formulário de contato 100% via javascript sem uso de um **PHP** por exemplo?
Se não der, existe alguma ferramenta tão simples quanto o **PHP** para este serviço?
Eu não entendo nada de **PHP**, e queria fazer um formulário de contato.

Quais saídas eu tenho?

Obrigado!

Comment: 100% via javascript não, você precisa do html.

Comment: Bom, você vai precisar obviamente enviar os dados do formulário para algum tipo de servidor, então se você não quer utilizar outra linguagem além do Javascript, uma saída é utilizar NodeJS no servidor.

Comment: [Como enviar emails utilizando JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8701/91) e [Como enviar e-mails somente com o básico de HTML5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você sempre vai precisar de um back-end que ira fazer o envio de email, isso é indispensavel (mas usando NodeJS, você faz o envio, o que torno só JS).

Um exemplo disso usando `JS` + `NodejS`

```
<input type="email" id="email">
<textarea id="msg"></textarea>
<button id="btn">Entrar em Contato</button>

<script>
   document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
      let email = document.getElementById('email').value
      let msg = document.getElementById('msg').value

      // Exemplo usando axios
      axios.post('SUA URL', {
         email: email,
         msg: msg
      })
      .then(response => {
          alert('FOI')
      })
      .catch(error => {
          alert('ERRO')
      })
   }
</script>


// Do lado do servidor com Node

'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
// Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: account.user, // generated ethereal user
            pass: account.pass  // generated ethereal password
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
        to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@blurdybloop.com>
        // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
    });
});
```

FONTE: https://nodemailer.com/about/

Comment: Show @Rafael! Só complementando miha pergunta... Você acha que a curva de aprendizado de NodeJS como server side mais fácil do que PHP?

Comment: @Jackson isso depende muito, eu comecei com `PHP`, e quando comecei a estudar `Node` achei muito mais facil, pois já trabalhava com `Javascript`

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado pela dica, Rafael =)